# I want to redirect without using proxy

Tags: web-services, web, proxy, network-programming

We are using norton to block sites.We use microtik routers.I want users to be redirected to a page when they tried to access a blocked site. Curruntly we are doing this using proxy. I want to know is there any way to redirect without using proxy?

Comment: Your question isn't precise enough. Please add some informations about your constraint, the kind of architecture, targeted OS,... And tools you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the DNS server the users are using, you could use a DNS Blacklist/Blackhole. You can configure it to block/redirect certain domain names.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL